# asp.net mvc identity 2 running two instance of different project

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I try to run 2 instance of two new ASP.NET MVC5 project with Identity 2.0 installed. Both application are created using the default MVC template and Set as individual authentication without any code modification.

I have run the first application within Visual Studio 2013 RC2 and have created a dummy user account using the web application register interface. After the above step, the Entity framework will create a dummy database with the dummy user login information. Then i login the first application and the login information was shown on header of the home page.

Next i run the second mvc application within the next instance of visual studio, when the web page is launched, i am surprised that i am already login to the second application which doesn't comes with any database. I do not know whats wrong. Under the _LoginPartial.cshtml the following code checks if the user is is authenticated and shows the Log off link.
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)

If the same test was run on different browser, problem wouldn't occurs. I guess something to do with cookies or browser cache. May i know how to avoid the above situation from happening? Or should it be normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time you logged in with your first project, the cookie for domain `localhost:1234` was set. Cookie contains the information about username and some other things. Second projects executes and your cookie is still set in the browser for the same domain: `localhost`. So your second application sees the cookie, reads data from it and accepts that the user is logged in.

No magic, only cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Was confused when two different web applications is able to interchangeably use the login cookie.

Comment: How can we fix this issue on local ? some time we use to run the multiple same time in same browser....

Comment: @PrasadRaja you can rename authentication cookie per application. Like this: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/07/rename-authentication-cookie-name-of-asp-net-identity/